# Is !! The same thing as ?. In kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-null-safety

I've read that using "!!" Instead of "?." In kotlin is not recommended. What is the difference between the 2 when checking for null in variables?

Comment: `obj?.getSomething()` will return null if `obj` is null, or the result of the method call if `obj` is not null. Whereas `obj!!.getSomething()` will throw an exception if `obj` is null.

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34342413/what-is-the-kotlin-double-bang-operator

Comment: And [Kotlin safe calls(.?) vs null chekcs(!!)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72380994/kotlin-safe-calls-vs-null-chekcs)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`!!` - is a developer's way of telling the compiler, trust me, I know this value will not be null. It is an **unsafe** way of converting a nullable value to a non nullable type. Unsafe meaning that it can throw a `NullPointerException` if the value is indeed null.

You can read more about it [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/null-safety.html#the-operator).

`?.` - is a developer's way of telling the compiler that in the case where the value is not null, do the rest of the logic followed after the ?. sign. This way is the **safe** way to access a nullable type.

You can read more about it [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/null-safety.html#safe-calls)

Comment: I would add that use cases for `!!` are almost always better served with `?: error("X should never be null because <insert reason here>")`. This allows programmers to understand why the previous programmer believed this value couldn't be null, and it allows to understand failures more easily when the invariant does change (and it will)

Answer (score 1):

"?." and "!!" are not the same.
"?." operator also called safe call operator which is used to safely access properties from a nullable object

[Refer to this link](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/null-safety.html#safe-calls)

Whereas "!!" is called a not-null assertion operator, it forcefully denotes a nullable type as not null. using this operator without any check for null will lead to NullPointerException.

[Refer to this link](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/null-safety.html#the-operator)

Answer (score 0):

No both are different.

`!!` operator is called as `double bang operator` in kotlin. It means you are forcefully nullable fields as non nullable. It will throw NullPointerException when the particular nullable field is null.

```
var s :String? = null
var b :String = s!!.lowerCase() // It will throw null pointer exception as you are asserting nullable variable as non null
```

`?.` is `null safe call operator.` It is used for making null safe access to particular field.

```
var s :String? = null
var b :String? = s?.lowerCase() //Here lowerCase will not execute because you are making safe call only if value is not null.

var s :String? = null
var b :String = b?.lowerCase() ?: ""
```

Additional thing if you need to b as non null during safecall operator you can use `?: (elvis)` operator to have default value if previous safe call statement is null.